# Having C wait for a finite amount of time for a user input before moving on with the script

Tags: c, windows, winapi

I currently have a small program I am writing that calls for a piece of code that will wait x seconds to see if the user inputs anything, and if no input is given moves on to conduct some more code. Such a thing would also be contained within a for loop such that once the further code has been executed, it waits the finite time period for input again. If input is given via keypress, the code then proceeds to execute further but differing code.
Initially I attempted to tackle this using a `while` loop, `<time.h>`'s `clock()` and `scanf()` but to no avail.
My latest attempt differs some what, but still does not yield the desired result.
My latest code is as follows:

```
int c;
char check[10];
    for(c=0;c<1000;++c){
        //do something
            int end=time(0)+(1);
            while(time(0)<end){
                fgets(check,10,stdin);
                if(*check=='\n'){
                break;
                }
            }
        //do the other stuff
        if(*check!='\n'){
            break;
        }
    }
    //even more stuff
```

I have declared all relevant header files at the top of my script but am now stumped as to how to proceed and I am using Windows. Any help would be appreciated.

Many thanks

Comment: Are you looking for [`sleep`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/sleep.3.html) ?

Comment: Do you want to check if user has input something within some time interval..

Comment: No not `sleep` as that would pause the execution which is almost what I'm trying to avoid as `fgets` and `scanf` do that but indefinetely. I suppose I'm looking for more what @sas has mentioned and want to check if the user has entered something in a time interval and progress if not.

Comment: It is operating system specific. On Linux & POSIX use [poll(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/poll.2.html) or [select(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/select.2.html). On Windows, you need to find out a multiplexing primitive in the WIN API. If your question is specific to Windows, you should tag it as such

Answer (score 3):

There is no suitable solution for this in standard C. `time.h` isn't useful for this task.

Operative systems have various non-standard API libraries that provide this kind of functionality, usually in form of an event that triggers a callback function.

Since you don't mention which system you are using, it won't be possible to give a good answer.

---

EDIT

On Windows you can use the [Windows console API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682010(v=vs.85).aspx), through windows.h. Here is an example for how to check if a key is pressed, without locking up the program in a busy-wait:

```
HANDLE hstdin = GetStdHandle(STD_INPUT_HANDLE);
DWORD fdwMode = ENABLE_WINDOW_INPUT; 
(void)SetConsoleMode(hstdin, fdwMode); 
(void)FlushConsoleInputBuffer(hstdin);

...

bool is_key_pressed (void)
{
  if(WaitForSingleObject(hstdin, 0) != WAIT_OBJECT_0)
  {
    return false;                                // no events flagged
  }

  DWORD cNumRead;
  INPUT_RECORD irInBuf[128]; 

  if (!ReadConsoleInput(hstdin,                  // input buffer handle 
                        irInBuf,                 // buffer to read into 
                        128,                     // size of read buffer 
                        &cNumRead))              // number of records read 
  {
    return false;
  }

  for (DWORD i = 0; i<cNumRead; i++)
  {
    if(irInBuf[i].EventType == KEY_EVENT)
    {
      return true;
    }
  }

  return false;
}
```

Comment: I'm using Windows if that helps.

Comment: @DeanBrunt You should have included that with the question. People are already suggesting various Unix solutions... Now what you probably want is the Windows console API. I'll edit the post.

Comment: Note however that I'm far from a Windows API expert. If you tag your question "windows" and "winapi" you'll attract the attention of such beasts, though.

Comment: Shall attempt to implement the solution you suggest as it seems somewhat promising, I have adjusted the tags according to see if I can lure any such 'beasts'. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 3):

You have to use select with a timeout and then perform the IO.
A starting point could be:

```
#include <sys/select.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    char buf[100];
    fd_set rfds;
    int r;

    FD_ZERO(&rfds);
    FD_SET(0, &rfds);
    struct timeval timeout;
    timeout.tv_sec = 3;
    timeout.tv_usec = 0;
    r = select(1, &rfds, NULL, NULL, &timeout);
    if(r == 0)
        printf("timeout!\n");
    else {
        fgets(buf, 100, stdin);
        printf("==> %s\n", buf);
    }
}
```

Comment: I have edited my original post to reflect this, but I am using windows which does not support `<sys/select.h>` from what I can see. I tried using an equivalent suggested elsewhere in `<Winsock2.h>` but this also didn't work.

Comment: But select() is Posix compliant... maybe, the header files to include are a bit different.

Comment: @DeanBrunt  "using windows" is an operating system, not a compiler.  Compilers exist for windows that this code compiles fine.  (just did it).  Disagree with [@Basile Starynkevitch](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41061571/having-c-wait-for-a-finite-amount-of-time-for-a-user-input-before-moving-on-with#comment69331312_41061571). The solution is not OS specific, but compiler specific.

Comment: select() is indeed POSIX compliant.  But that doesn't mean it works everywhere!  Windows doesn't *do* POSIX.

Comment: @chux, I suspect you're referring to Cygwin.  That's an emulation layer: Cygwin programs aren't really running on Windows, they're running on the emulation layer over top of Windows.

Answer (score 0):

Well, in your case, because you are waiting on users input, `select()` or `poll()` will be a good choise.

Comment: Have made attempts to do some reading on those too, but being new-ish to C I'm not entirely sure I fully understand how to use them. Would you mind writing a short generic example that I could try and get my head round please?